# how to call prototype function in html tag element

Tags: javascript

html element `ondragstart` I want to call a prototype function when I call it this way `console.log()` says `this.drag(event)` not a funciton

```
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="this.drag(event)"></div>
```

How can I achieve it in this manner ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to add event using `addEventListener`. Also where have you added `drag` function

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be? In that attribute handler, `this` will be the `HTMLDivElement`. Where is this object you're defining `drag` on?

Comment: after calling object.drag(event) it is still giving the same error  T.J Crowder

Comment: It shouldn't be down voted, I know 'this' means here the div element,  It was reference I just give

Answer (score 0):

When you say `this.drag(event)`, the `this` is the `<div>` that you made, so you try to call a method `drag` on the HTML element.

You can fix it like this:

```
<script>
function dragStarted(event) {
  console.log("Drag event fired");
}
</script>
<div draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStarted(event);"></div>
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Nope. This does not address OP's query. He has added a prototype function and wants to access it